# Commerce Node Checkout set node to sticky or front page

Tags: commerce, rules

I recently converted from MoneyScripts Pay-to-Publish to Drupal Commerce and am looking to re-create some of the functionality. I would like to have a [Commerce Node Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout) plan that sets nodes to "sticky at top of lists" or "promoted to front page" upon payment.

I imagine it can be done with rules, but I have been unable to figure it out. Has anyone implemented similar functionality? If so, how?